# Accessing table data with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to access the `<td>`'s in following:

```
<table class="datadisplaytable" summary="This table lists the scheduled meeting times and assigned instructors for this class..">
<caption class="captiontext">Scheduled Meeting Times</caption>
<tbody><tr>
<th class="ddheader" scope="col">Time</th>
<th class="ddheader" scope="col">Days</th>
<th class="ddheader" scope="col">Where</th>
<th class="ddheader" scope="col">Date Range</th>
<th class="ddheader" scope="col">Schedule Type</th>
<th class="ddheader" scope="col">Instructors</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="dddefault">8:35 AM - 9:55 AM</td>
<td class="dddefault">TR</td>
<td class="dddefault">Trottier Building 0100</td>
<td class="dddefault">Jan 05, 2015 - Apr 13, 2015</td>
<td class="dddefault">Lecture</td>
<td class="dddefault">Harry Leib </td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
```

I have a bunch of these tables in a HTML collection called `var data_tables` and I can successfully access the caption with `data_tables[0].childNodes[0].innerText`(i.e. for the first table in the collection). However when I try to access the `<td>`'s (for example the text "8:35 AM - 9:55 AM") with `data_tables[0].childNodes[1].childNodes[1].childNodes[0].innerText` I get "undefined" when using Chrome. What am I missing? Is the `<td>` not three layers of nodes deep from the `<table>`?

Answer (score 1):

You may be getting a text node instead of the `td` element.

Don't use `.childNodes` with tables. Instead use the `.tBodies`, `.rows` and `.cells` collections.

```
data_tables[0].tBodies[0].rows[1].cells[0].innerText
```

Also, I'd use `.textContent` instead of `.innerText` so that you're using the standard property.

Comment: Thanks that worked. Where can I find documentation on the standard properties to be used?

Comment: You're welcome. Mozilla has lots of JS docs: [MDN JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript)